# mailto in IE breaks after adding Search Core Results Web Part

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, mailto

I'm trying to create a link that pops open a new email in outlook:

```
<a href="mailto:someaddress@mail.com?subject=blah">Feedback</a>
```

and this works fine in firefox, but in IE9 it's literally redirecting the browser to "mailto:someaddress@mail.com?subject=blah".  The email window still pops up but I need IE to remain on the same page where the mailto link was clicked.

**EDIT:** I have now pinpointed this to being a SharePoint 2007 problem.  The mailto href works fine before adding a Search Core Results webpart to the page, but after adding the Core Results webpart, the previously described problem takes place.

Comment: How is your IE configured? The default mail program, I mean...

Comment: @Alfabravo Outlook is set up as the mail client and as far as I know, my IE is set to all the defualt settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still dont know what the exact cause of the problem is but I was able to get around it by doing the following:

Add a hidden iframe to the page:

```
<iframe id="emailiframe" src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

In the content editor web part that contains my "feedback" link, I set the source to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function feedbackEmail()
{
var iframe = document.getElementById("emailiframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "mailto:someaddress@mail.com?subject=blah");
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="feedbackEmail(); return false;">Feedback</a>
```

IE now does what it's supposed to.